# How to get accumulated-monthly data using query

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this query, it should display 3 rows of result under DAY column (210301, 201302, SUM).But for some reason, it only shows SUM row under DAY column. Idea is that '201301' row accumulates 31 days of data in January.
Can anyone point me out why they don't show up?

```
    SELECT X.*
 FROM
      ( 
        SELECT 
                    (CASE
                             WHEN DAY.DAY = 'SUM' THEN DAY.DAY
                             ELSE 
                             TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (DAY.DAY, 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMM') 
                       END
                    ) AS DAY,
                    MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT AS MNOT_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE_500K AS MOVIE_500K_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE_1M AS MOVIE_1M_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE AS MOVIE_CNT,
                    RSC.EXAM AS EXAM_CNT,
                    RSC.WEB AS WEB_CNT,
                    RSC.IMG AS IMG_CNT,
                    RSC.INTERRAC AS INTERRACTIVE_CNT,
                    RSC.DOC AS DOC_CNT,
                    MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT + RSC.MOVIE_500K + RSC.MOVIE_1M + RSC.MOVIE + RSC.EXAM + RSC.WEB + RSC.IMG + RSC.INTERRAC + RSC.DOC TOT_CNT
          FROM 
                    /* DATES */

                   (SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201301','YYYYMM'),LEVEL-1), 'YYYYMM') AS DAY
                      FROM DUAL
                      CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('201301','YYYYMM'),LEVEL-1 ) <= TO_DATE('201302', 'YYYYMM')
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'SUM' FROM DUAL
                    ) DAY LEFT OUTER JOIN

                   /* RESOURCE */
                    (
                     SELECT 
                                 NVL(DT_G.COMM_DT, 'SUM') COMM_DT
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_500K), 0) AS MOVIE_500K
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_1M), 0) AS MOVIE_1M
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE), 0) AS MOVIE
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.EXAM), 0) AS EXAM
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.DOC), 0) AS DOC 
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.IMG), 0) AS IMG
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.WEB), 0) AS WEB
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.INTERRAC), 0) AS INTERRAC
                       FROM 
                                (
                                 SELECT
                                              COMM_DT
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K END MOVIE_500K
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE_1M
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K+SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP11' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS EXAM
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP12' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS DOC
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP13' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS IMG
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP14' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS WEB
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP01' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS INTERRAC
                                  FROM (
                                              SELECT RSC_TP_DSCD, SUM(STDY_CNT) AS SUM_STD_CNT, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M) AS SUM_1M, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K) AS SUM_500K, COMM_DT
                                              FROM (
                                                        SELECT RSC_SNO, STDY_CNT, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K, COMM_DT
                                                          FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
                                                        WHERE PKG_SNO = 0  AND RSC_SNO != 0
                                                        AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201301', 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMM') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201311', 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMMDD')
                                                        ) CNT
                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN LRMS.V_LRRM_RSC RSC ON CNT.RSC_SNO = RSC.RSC_SNO
                                              GROUP BY RSC_TP_DSCD, COMM_DT
                                            ) SUMT
                                ) DT_G
                         GROUP BY ROLLUP(DT_G.COMM_DT)
                    ) RSC ON DAY.DAY = RSC.COMM_DT
                    /* MNOTE */
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (
                      SELECT NVL(SUM(STDY_CNT), 0) AS SUM_STD_CNT, NVL(COMM_DT, 'SUM') COMM_DT
                        FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
                      WHERE PKG_SNO != 0  AND RSC_SNO = 0
                                AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201301', 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMM') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201306', 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMM')
                      GROUP BY ROLLUP(COMM_DT)
                    ) MNOT  ON DAY.DAY = MNOT.COMM_DT
        ) X

 WHERE 1=1
 and X.TOT_CNT IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Without sample data, current and desired result, and a description of your table structure, your question is not going to get answers. You are letting the readers do extra guess work about information you should have provided in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of the null values in the sum field TOT_CNT

change the line

```
MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT + RSC.MOVIE_500K + RSC.MOVIE_1M + RSC.MOVIE + RSC.EXAM + RSC.WEB + RSC.IMG + RSC.INTERRAC + RSC.DOC TOT_CNT
```

to

`nvl(MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT,0) + nvl(RSC.MOVIE_500K,0) + nvl(RSC.MOVIE_1M,0) + nvl(RSC.MOVIE,0) + nvl(RSC.EXAM,0) + nvl(RSC.WEB,0) + nvl(RSC.IMG,0) + nvl(RSC.INTERRAC,0) + nvl(RSC.DOC,0) AS TOT_CNT`

and try

Comment: Then it shows "ora-00937 not a single-group group function" on WHEN DAY.DAY = 'SUM' THEN DAY.DAY     How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry please remove the aggregate function and try.
nvl(MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT,0) + nvl(RSC.MOVIE_500K,0) + nvl(RSC.MOVIE_1M,0) + nvl(RSC.MOVIE,0) + nvl(RSC.EXAM,0) + nvl(RSC.WEB,0) + nvl(RSC.IMG,0) + nvl(RSC.INTERRAC,0) + nvl(RSC.DOC,0) AS TOT_CNT

Comment: I just tried, and it does show '201301' and '201302' Thankyou! But still, I get no data under columns; MNOT_CNT, MOVIE_1M_CNT, MOVIE_CNT, EXAM_CNT, WEB_CNT, IMG_CNT, INTERRACTIVE_CNT, DOC_CNT for '201301' and '201302'. 'SUM' row displays data fine, but other two rows display no data. could you help me with this? I would so appreciate your help

Comment: Without checking the data, one cannot tell why that condition not returns any value. Please check the where condition
PKG_SNO != 0  AND RSC_SNO = 0 AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201301', 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMM') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('201306', 'YYYY-MM'), 'YYYYMM') is returning some values for '201301' and '201302'.